# Add custom block in transnational email

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, custom-block

I am using Magneto 2.3.5-p1, I want to add some custom values in my New Order Transactional email template using block, for that, I have created a custom template from `Marketing->Eamil Template` and assigned that template from `Store Configuration->Sales->Sales Email` I have added below custom block in my email template

```
{{block class="Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template" order=$order name="sample_name" template= "VENDOR_MODULE::checkoutFieldsEmail.phtml" area = "frontend"}}
```

and in `checkoutFieldsEmail.phtml` have added below code even I removed all PHP code and put simple HTML for testing but not showing in email only default content is showing.

I have already added a new column in the `sales_order` table and the name of the column is `Custom_column` and added some JSON data.

```
<?php
    $helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Data');
    $order = $block->getOrder();
    if($order):
    $_custom_value = $order->getCustom_column();
    $coafFields = json_decode($_custom_value,true);
?>
```

Comment: switch the scope to store view & website and check the field value. https://cdn.mageplaza.com/media/general/0MkD7af.png

Comment: @AmitBera didn't get your point.

Answer (score -1):

I had done same by following below instruction.

1. Create custom handler as "sales_email_order_content.xml" in app/code/vendor/package/view/frontend/layout/
2. Add below code in "sales_email_order_content.xml"

   ```
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sales_email_custom_content" template="Vendor_Package::order_email.phtml"/>
    </body>
   ```
3. create order_email.phtml under path app/code/Vendor/Package/frontend/templates/ and add your logic. In this file you can get order object as we will pass this to layout handler
4. Add below code in your custom Email template file

   {{layout handle="sales_email_order_content" order=$order area="frontend"}}

Hope it helps

Comment: still not working

Comment: okay can you add this code "{{layout handle="sales_email_order_content" order=$order area="frontend"}}" directly into new_order.html and check also which email html file is use. just change the content varify

Comment: Thanks @Amitkumar it is showing content now in email, but how to access $order in the template file?

Comment: You can use "<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>" and you can use assign this class "Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" to work with order items.

Comment: This is not working `<?php
    $_order = $block->getOrder();
    if($_order):
?>
<h1>Some content</h1>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: so in the email content phtml file you can try <?php $order = $this->getOrder(); echo "id==".$order->getId(); ?> i am getting id so you must get this.

Comment: Hi, Please upvote and accept the answer if you get solution so it will help to other members