# How to add Cart items in abandoned cart email template in magento2

Tags: magento2.3.4, abandoned-cart

How can we add the product list in abandoned cart email template in magento 2?

Comment: follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319538/add-custom-block-in-transnational-email/319574?noredirect=1#comment458097_319574. it may help you.

Comment: i have followed the above link code.but items are showing same for all customers.is there any way to add the product list in abandoned cart email template?

Comment: Yes you can add your own blockk class  instead this "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" and add product according to its template file.